# NullPointerException - android.view.Window.findViewById(int) - Why?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, nullpointerexception, android-relativelayout

I have had multiple problems with android app dev kit and I can't seem to fix it. I tried running my code and this is what shows up in logcat

Here is my main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
TextView output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
ArrayList <String> charzart = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList <String> color = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    Button converter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    int begin = 0;
    int total = 16777216;
    String text = input.getText().toString();

    ArrayList<Integer> hexa = new ArrayList<Integer>();


    //charzart array
    int b = text.length();

    for (int i = 1; i <= b; i++) {
        charzart.add(text.substring(i - 1, i));
    }

    //hexa array

    int a = text.length() - 1;

    for (int z = 0; z < charzart.size(); z++) {

        if (charzart.get(z).matches(" ")) {
            a--;
        }
    }


    int numb = total / a;

    for (int x = 0; x <= 16777216; x = x + numb) {
        hexa.add(x);
    }


    //changing into hexadecimal numbers

    for (int y = 0; y < hexa.size(); y++) {

        int cvalue = hexa.get(y);
        int one, two, three, four, five, six;

        one = cvalue / 1048570;
        cvalue = cvalue - one * 1048570;

        two = cvalue / 65356;
        cvalue = cvalue - two * 65356;

        three = cvalue / 4096;
        cvalue = cvalue - three * 4096;

        four = cvalue / 256;
        cvalue = cvalue - four * 256;

        five = cvalue / 16;
        cvalue = cvalue - five * 16;

        six = cvalue;

        if (one != 16) {

            String let = "";
            String fin = "#";

            switch (one) {
                case 0:
                    let = "0";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    let = "1";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    let = "2";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    let = "3";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    let = "4";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    let = "5";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    let = "6";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    let = "7";
                    break;
                case 8:
                    let = "8";
                    break;
                case 9:
                    let = "9";
                    break;
                case 10:
                    let = "A";
                    break;
                case 11:
                    let = "B";
                    break;
                case 12:
                    let = "C";
                    break;
                case 13:
                    let = "D";
                    break;
                case 14:
                    let = "E";
                    break;
                case 15:
                    let = "F";
                    break;
                default:
                    let = "x";
            }

            fin += let;
            let = "";

            switch (two) {
                case 0:
                    let = "0";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    let = "1";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    let = "2";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    let = "3";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    let = "4";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    let = "5";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    let = "6";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    let = "7";
                    break;
                case 8:
                    let = "8";
                    break;
                case 9:
                    let = "9";
                    break;
                case 10:
                    let = "A";
                    break;
                case 11:
                    let = "B";
                    break;
                case 12:
                    let = "C";
                    break;
                case 13:
                    let = "D";
                    break;
                case 14:
                    let = "E";
                    break;
                case 15:
                    let = "F";
                    break;
                default:
                    let = "x";
            }

            fin += let;
            let = "";

            switch (three) {
                case 0:
                    let = "0";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    let = "1";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    let = "2";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    let = "3";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    let = "4";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    let = "5";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    let = "6";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    let = "7";
                    break;
                case 8:
                    let = "8";
                    break;
                case 9:
                    let = "9";
                    break;
                case 10:
                    let = "A";
                    break;
                case 11:
                    let = "B";
                    break;
                case 12:
                    let = "C";
                    break;
                case 13:
                    let = "D";
                    break;
                case 14:
                    let = "E";
                    break;
                case 15:
                    let = "F";
                    break;
                default:
                    let = "x";
            }

            fin += let;
            let = "";

            switch (four) {
                case 0:
                    let = "0";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    let = "1";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    let = "2";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    let = "3";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    let = "4";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    let = "5";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    let = "6";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    let = "7";
                    break;
                case 8:
                    let = "8";
                    break;
                case 9:
                    let = "9";
                    break;
                case 10:
                    let = "A";
                    break;
                case 11:
                    let = "B";
                    break;
                case 12:
                    let = "C";
                    break;
                case 13:
                    let = "D";
                    break;
                case 14:
                    let = "E";
                    break;
                case 15:
                    let = "F";
                    break;
                default:
                    let = "x";
            }

            fin += let;
            let = "";

            switch (five) {
                case 0:
                    let = "0";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    let = "1";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    let = "2";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    let = "3";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    let = "4";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    let = "5";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    let = "6";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    let = "7";
                    break;
                case 8:
                    let = "8";
                    break;
                case 9:
                    let = "9";
                    break;
                case 10:
                    let = "A";
                    break;
                case 11:
                    let = "B";
                    break;
                case 12:
                    let = "C";
                    break;
                case 13:
                    let = "D";
                    break;
                case 14:
                    let = "E";
                    break;
                case 15:
                    let = "F";
                    break;
                default:
                    let = "x";
            }

            fin += let;
            let = "";

            switch (six) {
                case 0:
                    let = "0";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    let = "1";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    let = "2";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    let = "3";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    let = "4";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    let = "5";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    let = "6";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    let = "7";
                    break;
                case 8:
                    let = "8";
                    break;
                case 9:
                    let = "9";
                    break;
                case 10:
                    let = "A";
                    break;
                case 11:
                    let = "B";
                    break;
                case 12:
                    let = "C";
                    break;
                case 13:
                    let = "D";
                    break;
                case 14:
                    let = "E";
                    break;
                case 15:
                    let = "F";
                    break;
                default:
                    let = "x";
            }

            fin += let;
            let = "";


            color.add(fin);

            fin = "#";
        } else {
            color.add("#FFFFFF");
        }

    }


    //BUTTON

    converter.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    String end = "";
                    for (int p = 0; p < charzart.size(); p++) {

                        if (charzart.get(p).equals(" ")) {

                        }
                        else{

                            Spannable colorSpan = new SpannableString(charzart.get(p));
                            int fake = Integer.parseInt(color.get(p));
                            colorSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(fake), 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

                            end += colorSpan;
                        }


                    }

                    output.setText(end);
                }


            }
    );

}
```

Here's my layout xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.hitchhikingapps.rainbowz.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

        <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Convert"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginTop="124dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/input"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/input"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Insert Text here" />

        <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/output"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="78dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

And this is an error which I got it:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.hitchhikingapps.rainbowz/com.hitchhikingapps.rainbowz.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:2090)
                                                                            at com.hitchhikingapps.rainbowz.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:22)
                                                                            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Sorry for the great block of code, but I really don't understand what the problem is. Any help would be appreciate

Comment: add you activity code and layout

Comment: null pointer exception says that there is no view with given id, check your layouts

Comment: I added my code? Thank you responding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are initializing your views as global variables:

```
EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
TextView output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
```

The current context of your views here is `Window` and not `R.layout.activity_main`.

If you want to use `input` and `output` as global variables, you have only to declare them:

```
EditText input;
TextView output;
```

and initialize them in `onCreate()` after `setContentView()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
    output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The NPE is because you're calling `findViewById()` before `onCreate()` in the activity lifecycle before the activity has a `Window`. Move the `findViewById()` calls from member variable initialization to `onCreate()` and after `setContentView()` so that a non-null value can be returned.